# regular expression replacing duoble quotes keeping nested quotes as it is

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace each double quote of a csv record to be replaced with some other character , lets say @#@, keeping inner double quotes unchanged.

e.g. consider following record

```
123453,"The NFL is promoting the importance of annual mammogram screenings for women over 40 in the prevention of breast cancer through their "A Crucial Catch" campaign.","Pittsburgh Steelers","NFL"
```

from this record I want to replace double quotes with @#@ from each fields beginning & end so that it becomes

```
123453,@#@The NFL is promoting the importance of annual mammogram screenings for women over 40 in the prevention of breast cancer through their "A Crucial Catch" campaign.@#@,@#@Pittsburgh Steelers@#@,@#@NFL@#@
```

please notice "A Crucial Catch" is unchanged as it is inside already started  double quotes

Comment: Accept your recent questions !

Comment: Yeah, for exaple, this line: `"a",1,"c"` - how is the parser to know if those are a string, a number and a string, or just one long string containing inner double quotes and some commas? I think you can't do the thing you want without at least some escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for

```
"(?=,|$)|(?<=^|,)"
```

and replace that with `@#@`. This regex looks for a quote that is preceded or followed by a comma (or start/end of string).

So, in PHP:

```
$result = preg_replace('/"(?=,|$)|(?<=^|,)"/', '@#@', $subject);
```

changes

```
123453,"The NFL is promoting "A Crucial Catch".","Pittsburgh Steelers","NFL"
```

into

```
123453,@#@The NFL is promoting "A Crucial Catch".@#@,@#@Pittsburgh Steelers@#@,@#@NFL@#@
```

Answer (score 1):

I up-voted the comment, because you should accept answers to your questions that have good answers (I saw a couple in there)... but here is a possible solution:

```
<?php

$orig = '123453,"The NFL is promoting the importance of annual mammogram screenings for women over 40 in the prevention of breast cancer through their "A Crucial Catch" campaign.","Pittsburgh Steelers","NFL"';

$cols = explode(',', $orig);

function replace_end_quotes($val) {
    return preg_replace('#(^"|"$)#', "@#@", $val);
}

echo implode(",", array_map("replace_end_quotes", $cols));
```

As mentioned in the comment by @socha23, if there is a comma in one of the fields, my solution will not work.  However, if your line above was actually formatted to be valid CSV data, then using something like str_getcsv in place of explode would do the trick.

Comment: yes for csv I am using str_getcsv function, the file I mentioned is a text file with comma separated records in it and not a starndart csv file

Comment: I am doing this whole thing there is indeed a comma appearing betwenn one of the fields

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop through the file and create a string that reconstruct's this.

Although not terribly efficient you could try...

```
$out = "";

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $arr = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
            if (!ctype_digit($data[$i])) {
                $data[$i] = '@#@' . $data[$i] . '@#@';
            }
            $arr[] = $data[$i];
        }
        $out .= implode("", $arr) . "\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

// Write $out to file or whatever
```